# ajaxOnValidation and ajaxSubmitButton in Yii not working together

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I have a jQuery dialog popup form shown within an iframe on Yii. If the form validates, it needs to save and close, otherwise it needs to show with the errors. However, while the validateOnChange is working, the validateOnSubmit doesn't - clicking on submit just returns the output of the view, instead of the errors (or an empty array). I'm not really sure where to start with fixing it.

I have these options in the `beginWidget()` call:

```
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions' => array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    'validateOnChange'=>true,
    'validateOnType'=>false,
),
```

And I am using this code to generate the button:

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Submit', 'enter', array('success' => 'afterValidate()'));
```

I found a couple of other links talking about the problem of these two options not working together at: [Yii ajaxSubmitButton() with fields validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348581/yii-ajaxsubmitbutton-with-fields-validation) and 
http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2008. However, I'm not sure what to do with the suggested fix in the last link:

```
function afterValidate(form, data, hasError){
  if (!hasError) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{$postUrl}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()
    })
    .done(function ( response ) {
      // my successhandler
    })
    .fail(function ( xhr, status ) {
      // my error handler
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

The callback function is being called, but always fails, whether the data is valid or not.

So, how do I implement a jQuery dialog form in Yii?

Comment: To clarify: it's an iframe popup/modal window, and the form is inside the iframe? There are no forms or submit buttons in different iframes, right?

Comment: @Blowski, Have u solved this issue? i am also facing the same problem...

Comment: @Suriya no - I just worked around it.